# How to find out application name by PID (process id)

Tags: windows, process, pid, visualsvn-server, netstat

I'm trying to install VisualSVN server and have message  "Specified TCP port is occupied by another service". How I can find what service or app is using the 443 port?
"netstat -aon" shows me only

```
UDP    0.0.0.0:443            *:*        4252
```

The OS is Windows. And yes, I had VisualSvn Server installed on this computer before. Then I removed it (I do not see any SVN service running) and would like to reinstall.

Also I'd like to know what Authentication mode should I choose. Considering I want to have repository on external drive.

Thank you in advance,
Alex.

Answer (score 10):

- Use `netstat -anbv` on older Windows versions. You can find `netstat` tool reference at http://technet.microsoft.com/library/ff961504.

[image: netstat output]

- On the latest Windows versions, run [`Get-NetTCPConnection`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh826153.aspx) PowerShell cmdlet with PowerShell 5.

  For example, run this command to get the name of the process that's listening to port 443 on your computer:

  ```
  PS C:\> Get-Process -Id (Get-NetTCPConnection -LocalPort 443).OwningProcess

  Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K)     CPU(s)     Id  SI ProcessName
  -------  ------    -----      -----     ------     --  -- -----------
  143      15     3448      11024              4572   0 VisualSVNServer
  ```